# Django didnt receive email

Tags: python, django, email

i am trying to send email from the website that i create. It does not display any error but there are no email that I received.

here is my setting code

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my email's pswrd'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Here is the function

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def sentmes(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        subject = request.POST.get('subject')
        message = request.POST.get('message')

        data = {
            'name': name,
            'email': email,
            'subject': subject,
            'message': message
        }
        mail = '''
            New message: {}
            
            From: {}
        
        '''.format(data['message'], data['email'])
        send_mail(data['subject'], mail, ' ', ['myemail@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)

    return render(request, ' ')
```

this is the output that i get

> [14/Jun/2021 06:52:15] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 18516

Where is my mistake. Hope someone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a closer look at the user's guide.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/topics/email/
A good check is to use the console to have a feedback, while testing.
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
and to test your parameters via the shell.
If it works, switch to smtp,
It it works, then implement your function.
As you use the smtp backend, make sure that all the parameters are the right ones.